# Load all expandablelistview items immediately

Tags: android, android-viewpager, xamarin, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

I have an expandablelistview that is backed by an adapter that handles loading data as the user scrolls down the list. As it scrolls, it dynamically calls the GetGroupView and GetChildView methods in the adapter to load content that is about to come into view, which is the default behavior. Very straight-forward stuff.

This expandablelistview has some rows that are more intensive to load, specifically it has multiple viewpagers. The scrolling down the screen becomes choppy when it gets to the rows containing viewpagers, due to the UI work necessary to setup and display them. However, once the user has scrolled to the bottom of the screen, scrolling back up and down again is fast and smooth, as the rows are now cached so don't need to be recreated.

What I would like to do is when the expandablelistview is created and bound to the adapter, somehow force it to load ALL of its rows, rather than just the top rows. That way there is no creating of views going on as the user scrolls down the screen, so the scrolling with be smooth. I don't see any method on the expandablelistview or the adapter to accomplish this, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Well one (perhaps not too efficient) way would be to scroll through all the list behind the user's back. Here's an example:

```
// Show loading animation (like a progress dialog)

// Expand all groups
for (int i=0; i<mExpAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
    mExpList.expandGroup(i);
}

// Scroll to last child
mExpList.smoothScrollToPosition(mExpList.getCount());

mExpList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView v, int firstVis, int visCount, int total) {
        if (firstVis+visCount == total) {
            // When the scrolling is done, collapse the groups
            for (int i=0; i<mExpAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
                mExpList.collapseGroup(i);
            }
            // Scroll to the 1st item
            mExpList.setSelectedGroup(0);
            // Remove the scroll listener
            mExpList.setOnScrollListener(null);

            // Hide the loading animation
        }
    }
});
```

Note that `smoothScrollToPosition` is kind of slow you may want to scroll using other methods or even imitate touches on the ExpListView using `dispatchTouchEvent` but that might be an overkill :-)